# <thead> Missing on Second Page after Insert Page

Tags: c#, printing

Im doing a aspx page for print only, inside my html that consists of few things, the table inside  I want it to be display on every page.

HTML

```
<thead>
<table> </table>
</thead>
<tbody>
<asp:gridview></asp:gridview>
</tbody>
```

c#

```
// I tried to break it on the row I want
foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
{
    if (row.RowIndex == Convert.ToInt32(breaking[z]))
    {
        row.Attributes["style"] = "page-break-after:always;";
    }
}
```

After I upgrade to IE 11, the header wont appear on second page. Then I tried using back IE 8, but that are a big space between `thead` and `tbody` in first page.
Anyone can help?

Comment: I see you're testing this on IE. Might I suggest boycotting IE?

Comment: Because currently I think this "row.Attributes["style"] = "page-break-after:always;"; "   only work for me now, anything suggestion for me to do the print feature?